# Finding and returning the value at location index in a list

Tags: list, python-3.x, return, location

Could my current code work for this function? Here is the goal of what I am trying to do first and then my current attempt

Look at list of values, xs. Find and return the value at location index. When index is invalid for xs, return response instead.

Current code:

```
def get(xs, index, response=None):
    xs=[]
    i=0
    for i in xs:
        try:
            while i<len(xs):
                index=xs.index(xs,index)
                index = i
            return i 
        except:
            return response
```

Thanks any help is appreciated

Comment: what is it that you're trying to do exactly?

Comment: It definitely wont work, given you are reassigning `xs = []` so the the `for` loop will never be entered. Looks like you have a number of layers of looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be very confused about what you are trying to do...

So if I understand correctly you want to return `xs[index]` if it exists otherwise `response`, a simple way to do that following the EAFP principle is:

```
def get(xs, index, response=None):
    try:
        return xs[index]
    except IndexError:
        return response
```

Comment: I like how we both understood completely opposite things :-)

Comment: Yeah, I gave up trying to interpret the code given the degree of confusion and just tried to answer the english question. But we came up with the same pattern.

Comment: Can't blame you on this one.

Comment: Thanks guys I was definitely confused about how to accomplish the goal

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of issues here, let's break them down by segments:

- You re-assign the name of the list you pass in thereby effectively losing the list you're searching in:

  ```
  xs=[]
  ```

  there's no need to do that, that line can be removed.
- You assign a value to `i` (reminiscent of `C`) which gets overwritten when the loop begins and you use a `for-loop` when you don't really need to:

  ```
  i=0
  for i in xs:
  ```

  again, this too can be removed.
- You use a `try-except` with a bare `except`; you should specify the exception which could be raised here which is `ValueError`.

  ```
  try:
     # content
  except ValueError:
      return response
  ```
- You're using a `while` loop getting the `index` (and specifying `start`), re-assigning it, and then returning it; it doesn't make much sense. You're really looking for `return xs.index(index)`.

  Again, you could really replace all that code with `xs.index(index)`

All in all, your function could look like this:

```
def get(xs, index, response=None):
    try:
        return xs.index(index)
    except ValueError:
        return response
```